# Is there a closed form solution or an efficient solver for this linearly constrained quadratic minimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix and $u\in\mathbb R^m$. Denote by $0\preccurlyeq x$ for some vector $x$ in $\mathbb R^m$ the relation such that $\forall i$, $0\leq x_i$. I am trying to solve the following minimization problem :
\begin{align*}
\min_{\substack{v\in\mathbb R^n:\\0\preccurlyeq Av}} \left\| v-A^T u \right\|_2^2 
\end{align*}

I am wondering if there is a nice closed form solution to this problem or if there are some good algorithm to solve it. If it can be of any help, we can assume $0\preccurlyeq u$.

---

Since this is convex, the KKT conditions are sufficient, here they are ($\mu$ are the lagrange multipliers) :
\begin{cases}
2v-2A^Tu-A^T\mu=0\\
0\preccurlyeq Av\\
0\preccurlyeq \mu\\
\mu^T A v = 0
\end{cases}

I tried playing around with those without much success.

Comment: Why not rename $A^\top u$? The variable is not $u$, after all

Comment: Isn't this about the distance of a given point to a given polytope?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes I think we could rename $A^Tu$ into $u'$ but I don't know if the fact that $u'$ is in the span of $A^T$ makes any difference so I preferred to keep it that way. Also yes it is exactly the distance of a point to a polytope. I don't know many method to solve this but from what I read, this can be solved efficiently for instance using the elipsoid method. Any additional information would be most welcome, for instance I am still not convinced that there is no simple closed form for this.

Comment: Well, if $v$ is in the polytope, the distance is zero

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156105/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3707984/339790)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo you mean if $u'=A^T u$ is in the polytope ? Yes I agree, and in this case of course $v=A^Tu$, I am more interested in the other case.

Comment: Is the feasible region a convex cone?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes $\{ v\in\mathbb R^n : 0\preccurlyeq Av \}$ is a pointed convex cone.